# Assign part of a vector to itself using std::vector::assign()

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Let's say I have a vector(v1) of size 10. Now I want to only keep parts of the elements, using:
    `v1.assign(v1.begin() + 2, v1.begin() + 6);`

What I'm not sure is, whether the original elements will be destroyed before assignment. If they are destoyed first, then I cannot rely on the original data.

This [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azbhc96f.aspx) seems to indicate that elements are erased first. However, a quick experiment tells me that the data are correctly assigned to itself.

So what is happening when assigning part of a vector to itself ?

Comment: You could also `v1.erase(v1.begin()+6, v1.end()); v1.erase(v1.begin(), v1.begin()+2);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the C++14 standard Table 100 — Sequence container requirements (in addition to
container)

The expression `a.assign(i,j)` has a pre-condition that `i` and `j` are not iterators into a.  Since

```
v1.assign(v1.begin() + 2, v1.begin() + 6);
```

Uses iterators that are iterators into `v1` so you have violated that pre-condition

If you want to reset the vector to contain a subrange then you can copy those elements into a temporary vector and then assign that temporary vector back to main vector.  This should be a move operation(C++11 and above) so no additional copies are made.

```
v = std::vector<decltype(v)::value_type>(v.begin() + 2, v.begin() + 6);
```

As pointed out in the comments from [Benjamin Lindley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440119/benjamin-lindley) and [Barry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2069064/barry) we can use [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) and [move iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator) like

```
std::copy(std::make_move_iterator(v.begin() + 2), std::make_move_iterator(v.begin() + 6), 
          std::make_move_iterator(v.begin()));
```

Comment: Though this is not what I'm asking but thanks. If a temporary vector is used, I would use an assign() + swap(), which will be less expensive than a copy() + assign() I think.

Comment: @vlursk This should be as efficient as you can do it.

Comment: I think it would be more efficient to copy the vector to itself, and erase extraneous elements. No need for an allocation. `std::copy(v.begin() + 2, v.begin() + 6, v.begin()); v.resize(6 - 2);`

Comment: While we're at it, `std::copy` with move iterators!

Comment: @Barry Why not `std::move` (the algorithm version)?

Comment: The move iterator version does not compile: `error: using rvalue as lvalue`, but even if it did it would not cut the tail from the original vector and would thus need an additional call to erase.

Answer (score 1):

From the C++11 Standard:

> **23.3.6.2 vector constructors, copy, and assignment**
>
> ```
> template <class InputIterator>
> void assign(InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
> ```
>
> 11 Effects:
>
> ```
> erase(begin(), end());
> insert(begin(), first, last);
> ```

In other words, don't use:

```
v1.assign(v1.begin() + 2, v1.begin() + 6);
```

By the time `insert` is called, `first` will be an invalid iterator.

Comment: I was trying to find that in the C++14 standard and I could not find it.  It looks like they removed it.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I don't see it there either. Strange.

Comment: @NathanOliver In the sequence containers table, there's still a requirement that `i`,`j` are not iterators into `a` for `a.assign(i,j)` (er, which you already found)

Comment: @Barry Yeah.  I just knew had seen what R Sahu quoted but I could not find it so I fell back to the table.