# std::vector<T>::assign using a subrange valid?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

I want to convert a vector into a sub-range of that vector, for example by removing the first and last values.  Is the use of the assign member function valid in this context?

```
std::vector<int> data = {1, 2, 3, 4};
data.assign(data.begin() + 1, data.end() - 1);
// data is hopefully {2, 3}
```

[Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign) states that

> All iterators, pointers and references to the elements of the container are invalidated. The past-the-end iterator is also invalidated.

This invalidation, however, doesn't appear to happen until the [end of assign](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/vector#L1462).

To be safe, I could just go with the following but it seems more verbose:

```
std::vector<int> data = {1, 2, 3, 4};
data = std::vector<int>{data.begin() + 1, data.end() - 1};
// data is now {2, 3}
```

Comment: Previous similar question, but answers may not be up-to-date: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36338603/assign-part-of-a-vector-to-itself-using-stdvectorassign

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `__invalidate_all_iterators` function that your link refers to is merely a debugging tool. It doesn't "cause" the iterators to be invalidated; It effectively reports that the iterators have been invalidated by the previous actions. It may be that this debugging tool might not catch a bug caused by this assignment.

It is a precondition of `assign` that the iterators are not to the same container. A precondition violation results in undefined behaviour.

Standard quote (latest draft):

> [sequence.reqmts] `a.assign(i,j)` Expects: T is Cpp17EmplaceConstructible into X from *i and assignable from *i.
>   For vector, if the iterator does not meet the forward iterator requirements ([forward.iterators]), T is also Cpp17MoveInsertable into X.
>   **Neither i nor j are iterators into a.**

Your safe alternative is correct.

If you want to avoid reallocation (keeping in mind that there will be unused space left), and if you want to avoid copying (which is important for complex types, doesn't matter for `int`), then following should be efficient:

```
int begin_offset = 1;
int end_offset = 1;
if (begin_offset)
    std::move(data.begin() + begin_offset, data.end() - end_offset, data.begin());
data.erase(data.end() - end_offset - begin_offset, data.end());
```

Comment: Also you should prefer coming up with a "view" rather than doing this at all. Or, if you really want to reclaim the memory, just do two erases!

Comment: Also there are better versions of the OP's "correct" solution on the page uneven_mark linked to, which will permit moving of the elements (granted, who cares for `int`)

Comment: It's kind of a shame cppreference doesn't mention this. I might make an edit later

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit added efficient suggestion.